# TeamViewer IP and VPN

Tags: vpn, ip, remote-access, teamviewer

If I'm connected to a remote computer with TeamViewer, and then I use that remote computer to make other connections to the Internet (e.g. my banking web site), which IP address will be recorded by the site?  My IP address that I am using TeamViewer on, or the IP address of the remote computer I am connected into?

Also, does a VPN get around any IP leakage if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access your bank website from the remote computer you are TeamViewer'd into, your bank web site will capture the IP address of the remote computer.  All you're doing is looking at the remote computer's screen.  You are not in any other way redirecting or proxying traffic to/from that remote machine.

As for TeamViewer itself, the TeamViewer client on both machines connect to a broker service on TeamViewer's servers.  The routing of the connection between two TeamViewer clients is handled by them based on the TeamViewer ID number of each computer.

Comment: @elmonko; please mark the answer as the correct one.  A) so I get the credit, and B) so future visitors can know it.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: Of course, had to wait 3 mins to do it though....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know TeamViewer works as the middle man.

You connect to teamviewer server and so does the client. All traffic flows through there servers.

The data is encrypted via 256 Bit AES. The question is do you trust teamviewer.

Regarding IPs:

```
Your External IP -> Teamviewer IP
Teamviewer IP -> Client IP
```

Comment: I trust teamviewer as much as any other software, I'm just curious which IP address is being recorded